# Oracle - SQL ID from which procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I found few SQL IDs in AWR report. How to know, from which PLSQL object is it getting called based on sql id? As AWR removes extra spaces, user_source will not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the statement in the shared pool, then [V$SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/V-SQL.html) view has `PROGRAM_ID` column, which is the `OBJECT_ID` of the PL/SQL objects from [ALL_OBJECTS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/ALL_OBJECTS.html). It event tells you the position in `PROGRAM_LINE#` column.

The above is not stored in AWR, so if you do not have the statement in the shared pool, then best you can get is `ACTION` and `MODULE` from [DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/DBA_HIST_SQLSTAT.html), but that will work only if the PL/SQL sets those attributes properly.